# Scan result QR condition

Tags: android, conditional-statements, zbar

i created a QR code scanner with zbar [here](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android/examples/CameraTest/src/net/sourceforge/zbar/android/CameraTest)
i wanna make some condition for example like this

```
 // define scan result
 // scanResult = "toolkit1"; 
 Toast.makeText(this, scanResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 if (scanResult == "toolkit1")
    Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 else 
    Toast.makeText(this, "fail : " +scanResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i'm very sure if scanResult from my app is 'toolkit1'
but everytime i launch app it's go to fail section

but if i define manual scan result var, it's not have problem
any idea why i can't perform simple condition in zbar?

Comment: scanResult is a String use scanResult.equals("toolkit1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `.equals()` for String comparison? The `==` could work too, but that depends on the JVM optimizing the String resources in your app...